# Secrets in development

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

In development is there a good way to store secrets in environment variables and not to have them in git? In VS `Properties -> Debug -> Environment variables` it is possible to set it but I guess it is stored somewhere in .vs directory. Should it be committed?

I red [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=linux) and it sounds too complicated for such a simple task. Also I want to have same secret loading code for development and production.

Comment: The task isn't simple, but the article makes it so. It's not complicated and what you describe would expose those secrets to every application. Environment variables are *OS* environment variables. Depending on their type (system or user), every application running on your machine or every app running when you log in will be able to read them

Comment: In any case nothing prevents you from storing secrets in env variables and reading them using the configuration extension. Secrets is just another configuration provider, the same as every other one. All produce the same `section:subsectiov:valueName` pairs. This means you can read config values from env variables, the secrets file, the database, or *your* own provider and the latest one will override all previous values

Comment: Think what `dotnet user-secrets` does for a moment. It puts some values in an app-specific folder under your account. That's it. Nothing more. All you have to use it then is use `AddUserSecrets`. That's it. The rest of the article talks about the Configuration system only, which your application *already* uses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is outdated documentation. With Core 3.0 you don't need to add anything special to template ASP project, it almost works out of the box.

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

`Configuration` is going to have values from appsettings.json overridden by secrets.json overridden by environment variables.